# @Bean (autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)

Tags: spring

What is the purpose of setting the autowire property of **@Bean** to ***Autowire.BY_NAME***

Looking at the JavDocs, I dont really know when I would use this, or why it would be set to ***Autowire.BY_NAME***

```
/**
 * Are dependencies to be injected via autowiring?
 */
Autowire autowire() default Autowire.NO;
```

I have an existing prototype bean that is created with

```
@Bean (autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
```

But I dont understand why.
The comments only state:

> Note: We have to explicitly set Autowire.BY_NAME in the bean
>   definitions to be able to use @Autowired in other spring config
>   classes

Does this mean we have to set a bean to @Bean (autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME) in order to be able to use the Bean with @Autowired and it will be autowired by name from the @Bean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Bean(autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME)` is the equivalent of this xml configuration:

```
<bean class="Person" id="person" autowire="byName"></bean>
```

which indicates whether the bean created using the above `Person` class, needs to have its fields autowired in "by name" - if the test bean above has a field say `address`, Spring will look for a bean with name `address` to inject as a dependency(not by type `Address`).

This is typically used if it is possible that there are more than 1 instances of a particular type, then you would select the specific instance using a name - again consider the example above if there were to be two address beans with names `addressHome`, `addressWork` and if `Person` class had a field with name `addressHome` and its set to `Autowire.BY_NAME`, the bean with name `addressHome` will be set to the field. Had it been `Autowire.BY_TYPE` it would have failed as there are two instances of address of the same type `Address`

Comment: I tried in Spring 5, It seems @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME) is depreciated. May I know what would be alternative for that now. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
As @Bean (autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME) is deprecated.
```

No syntactical alternative, Autowire by Name is understood.
You just have to provide same name as @Bean method name or @Component name.